# Unable to import sql file in postgresql on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, postgresql, ubuntu-14.04

I 'm trying to import sql file in my database on postgresql using command line  but I'm getting the following error.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please have look at [this wiki resource](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Things_to_find_out_about_when_moving_from_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL) about quoting identifiers